# I want a hint to solve the given nonlinear system problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The critical point $(0,0)$ for the system 
$$
\begin{cases}
\ x'(t) = \;\,x   {}-2y {}+y^2 \sin(x)\\[1ex]
\ y'(t) = 2x  {}-2y {}-3y \cos(y^2)
\end{cases}
$$ is a

1. Stable spiral point
2. Unstable spiral point
3. Saddle point
4. Stable node

These equations are form of the nonlinear system, I know only linear system. Can anyone give hint to understand, how to solve this type of problem?

Comment: Linearise at the critical point.

Answer (score 4):

The Jacobi matrix of the given system, is :

$$J(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 + y^2\cos(x) & -2 + 2y\sin(x)\\2 & -2-3\cos(y^2) + 6y^2\sin(y^2) \end{bmatrix} $$

The matrix for the stable point, is given as :

$$J(0,0) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ 2 & - 5\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, for the eigenvalues, it is :

$$\det(J(0,0) - \lambda I) = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda ^2 + 4\lambda -1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow -2 \pm \sqrt{5}$$

The product of the two eigenvalues, is $\lambda_1 \lambda_2 >0$ and thus the critical point $(0,0)$ is an unstable saddle point.

Our result, graphically :

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad $[image]

Comment: It appears to me that the critical point is a *saddle*, since there are two real eigenvalues $-2 \pm \sqrt 5$ of *opposite* signs.

Comment: Here the product of two eigen values is negative. So critical point will be a saddle point . Is it correct?

Comment: @user118413:  yes, that is correct.

Comment: I apologise, lost in translation from Greek. Yes, you're correct (and I'm correcting now).

Comment: Yeah , lots of thanx

Comment: @user118413 No probs. Make sure you include the tag dynamical-systems as well in your post, it's exactly what these questions are about.

Comment: @Rebellos: shouldn't you get  $1 + y^2 \cos x$ and $6 y^2 \sin \left(y^2\right)-3 \cos \left(y^2\right)-2$ in the Jacobian results?